# Shortcut key for moving between source and design view in ASP.net Pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I know that F7/Shift F7 will switch between Code behind and ASPX pages, but
what's the shortcut to switch between source and design view in Visual studio for asp.net Pages?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Ctrl-Page Down` and `Ctrl-Page Up`

Answer (score 3):

*There are three view in visual studio. Desing, Split and Source. We can switch between them using Ctrl+PageUp and Ctrl+PageDown keys.*

---

**Ctrl + PageUp**

<<-- Design <<-- Split <<-- Source <<-- Design <<-- Split <<-- Source <<--

**Ctrl + PageDown**

-->> Design -->> Split -->> Source -->> Design -->> Split -->> Source -->>

---

So for changing view From **Design to Source** use **Ctrl+PageUp**

and for changing view From **Source to Design** use **Ctrl+PageDown**